# How to solve entry in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried this php code:

```
echo $_SESSION['user_id']."<br />\n";
$sql = "UPDATE user_passwords SET status ='off' WHERE users_id = 'user_id'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

output in html notify:

```
161 // Nr. user from users
Record updated successfully
```

But NO record in MySQL....
When I modify php like this:

```
echo $_SESSION['user_id']."<br />\n";
$sql = "UPDATE user_passwords SET status ='off' WHERE users_id ='161'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

output in html notify:

```
161 // Nr. user from users
Record updated successfully
```

and in MySQL is all OK.

Where could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is here `WHERE users_id = 'user_id'";`

it should be your session variable in the place of that `user_id`

```
<?php

echo $_SESSION['user_id']."<br />\n";

$sql = "UPDATE user_passwords SET status ='off' WHERE users_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

?>
```

NB:Use prepared statements. to protect against sql injections.

Answer (score 1):

$sql = "UPDATE user_passwords SET status ='off' WHERE users_id = '**user_id**'";

In first attempt you're trying to use string 'user_id' as user's id.
You should use `$_SESSION['user_id']` instead or define a php variable:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Which then you can use, but with '$' prefix so `$user_id`

Plus: you shouldn't use apostrophe in SQL when you expect a variable to be integer. 
Plus2: you should use **mysqli_real_escape_string** when handling $_SESSION, $_GET and $_POST variables

Comment: Thank you, but unsolved.... 
In output html Record updated successfully, but no in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing variable wrongly in sql string,

```
$sql = "UPDATE user_passwords SET status ='off' WHERE users_id = 'user_id'";
                                                                  ^
```

In above string you don't have $ sign with variable name which didn't find right user id you should use.

```
$sql = "UPDATE user_passwords SET status ='off' WHERE users_id = '$user_id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your update query **'user_id'** acts like a **value** not a **variable** containing the session user id. That's why it's not working.

Try like this

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = "UPDATE user_passwords SET status ='off' WHERE users_id = '$user_id'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```